# bfcat - encode a file as a brainf*** program

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck

## Challenge

Write a program or function that given a string, returns a valid Brainfuck program that when compiled and executed as Brainfuck, returns that string..

1. Assume all inputs are encoded as ASCII.
2. Assume the outputted BF program will execute in an environment with an infinite tape.
3. Assume the pointer starts at cell 0 with every cell initialized to a value of zero.
4. Each example below represent one possible correct output for the given input. In particular, the examples include extra newlines and spaces to help human readability. Solutions are free to format the outputted BF code in any way.
5. The tape is doubly infinite.
6. All cells provided by the interpreter are exactly 8-bit cells. Overflow and underflow wrap around in a predictable and sane matter.

### Examples

#### Space string

Given the input   , your program/function could return:

```
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
++ .
```

#### Exclamation point

Given the input `!` , your program/function could return:

```
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++
.
```

#### Two letters

Given the input `hi` , your program/function could return:

```
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++

+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++
+++++ +++++

++++
.
+
.
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins. Good luck.

Comment: More testcases please.

Comment: What exactly are the guidelines mentioned in [Revision 9](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/83832/9)?

Comment: I'm reopening this. I think Peter's concerns have been addressed and we have a fairly clear consensus on what counts as a duplicate, and this challenge doesn't meet those criteria.

Comment: "Overflow and underflow wrap in a predictable and sane manner" - so 127+1 wraps to 0 and -128-1 also wraps to 0, correct? That's one possible predictable and sane manner.

Comment: @immibis Exactly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
O”+ẋp“.>
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T-KAnSvhuotw4oCcLj4&input=&args=J2hpJw)

#### Sample run

For input `hi`, this program prints

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++>
```

(without the linefeeds) which, in turn, [prints `hi`](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKys-KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLisrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKz4&input=).

#### How it works

```
O”+ẋp“.>  Main link. Argument: s (string)

O         Ordinal; convert each character in s into its code point.
 ”+       Yield the character '+'.
   ẋ      Repeat '+' k times, for each k in the code points.
     “.>  Yield the string ".>".
    p     Take the Cartesian product of both results.
```

Comment: Yours don't work on limited memory, mine does.

Comment: Not really. We both store the entire output in memory before printing. For BF interpreters with a large enough tape, that will become an issue long before the tape does.

Comment: Why doesn't `.>` appear in the output?

Comment: @cat Because *Cartesian product* (`p`) is shorter than *append to each* (`;€`). These ouput programs double the cell after printing and before switching. Since we never revisit the cell, it doesn't affect the output.

Comment: @Dennis ahh, interesting.

Answer (score 62):

### Brainfuck, <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```
,[>+++[>+++++++<-]>[<++>>+++<-]<+<[>.<-]>+++.>>-.,]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs-KysrWz4rKysrKysrPC1dPls8Kys-PisrKzwtXTwrPFs-LjwtXT4rKysuPj4tLixd&input=aGVsbG8)

Example output for `hi` (without the linefeeds):

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>
```

#### Explanation

This moves across the tape while writing the program. The surrounding `,[...,]` is a standard input loop. For each character, we use four cells:

```
[... x a b c ...]
```

where `x` is the cell we write the input to.

```
>+++[>+++++++<-]
```

This part uses cell `a` to write a `21` into cell `b` via a standard multiplication of `3` and `7`.

```
>[<++>>+++<-]
```

Now we use that `21` to write `42` into `a` and `63` into `c` by multiplying by `2` and `3` respectively. Then `<+<` moves back to cell `x` while turning the `42` into a `43` (the code point of `+`). Recap:

```
[... x 43 21 63 ...]
```

Now the main output loop:

```
[>.<-]
```

That is, while decrementing `x` we print one `+` each time.

```
>+++.
```

After we're done we reuse the `+` cell, by adding `3` to give `.`.

```
>>-.
```

Finally, we move to the `63`, decrement it to `62` (`>`) and output that as well. The next iteration will use this cell as `x`.

Comment: I'd give a bounty to this if I had more rep.

Answer (score 37):

## Brainfuck, <s>39</s> <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
-[-[>]<--<--],[[>.<+]>+.--.+<,]
```

The algorithm that places **45** on the tape is taken from [Esolang's Brainfuck constants](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#45).

This answer assumes that the output program's interpreter has wrapping, bounded cells; and that `,` zeroes the current cell (implying that the output program is run without input). [Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LVstWz5dPC0tPC0tXSxbWz4uPCtdPisuLS0uKzwsXQ&input=Q29kZSBHb2xm)

For a (longer) solution that works unconditionally, see [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83912).

#### Test run

For input `Code Golf`, the following output is generated.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.,
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLiwtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLiwtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0uLC0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLiwtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS4sLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0uLC0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0uLC0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0uLC0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0uLA&input=)

#### How it works

We begin by putting the integer **45** (character code of `-`) into a cell of the tape. The following code achieves this.

```
-      Decrement cell 0, setting it to 255.
[      While the cell under the head in non-zero:
  [>]    Advance to the next zero cell.
  <--    Decrement the cell to its left.
  <--    Decrement the next cell to the left.
]
```

Before we enter the loop, the tape looks like this.

```
         v
000 000 255
```

These three cells – **-2**, **-1**, and **0** – are the only ones we'll use in this program.

In the first each iteration of the loop, the rightmost cell is, then that cell and middle cell are decremented twice, leaving the following state.

```
     v
000 254 252
```

In the next 126 iterations, the initial `-` decrements the middle cell, `[>]<` jumps to the rightmost cell, and `--<--` decrements the middle and the right cell. As a result, **3** is subtracted from the middle cell (modulo **256**) and **2** is subtracted from the rightmost cell.

Since **254 ÷ 3 (mod 256) = (254 + 256) ÷ 3 = 510 ÷ 3 = 170** and **252 ÷ 3 = 84**, the rightmost cell is zeroed out before the middle one, leaving the following state.

```
     v
000 132 000
```

Similarly to the first iteration of the loop, the next iteration now subtracts **3** from the middle cell and **2** from the leftmost cell, placing the head on the leftmost cell.

```
 v
254 129 000
```

Subsequent iterations, as in the 126 iteration before them, subtract **3** from the leftmost cell and **2** from the rightmost cell.

Since **254 ÷ 3 (mod 256) = 170** and **129 ÷ 2 (mod 256)** is undefined, this is done 170 times, leaving the following state.

```
 v
000 045 000
```

The cell under the head is zero; the loop ends.

Now we're ready to generate output.

```
,      Read a character from STDIN and put it the leftmost cell.
[        While the leftmost cell is non-zero:
  [        While the leftmost cell is non-zero:
    >.     Print the content of the middle cell ('-').
    <-     Increment the leftmost cell.
  ]      If the leftmost cell held n, the above will print 256 - n minus signs
         which, when executed, will put n in cell 0 of the output program.
  >      Increment the middle cell, setting it to 46 ('.').
  .      Print its content ('.').
  --     Decrement the middle cell twice, setting it to 44 (',').
  .      Print its content (',').
         When executed, since the output program receives no input, the above
         will zero cell 0 of the output program.
  +      Increment the second cell, setting it back to 45 ('-').
  <,     Go back to the leftmost cell and read another character from STDIN.
]      Once EOF is reached, this will put 0 in the leftmost cell, ending the loop.
```

Comment: Why does the resulting BF not translate back to the input string for me? This is the [interpreter](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/) I'm using, which has worked for the other answers.

Comment: That interpreter has a lot of settings. For the 32 byte version, you'd need *dynamic memory* and *end of input: `\0`*.

Answer (score 12):

## Brainfuck, <s>35<sub>13</sub></s> 43 bytes

```
++[>+<------],[[>.>+<<-]>+++.->[<.>-]<--<,]
```

This answer makes *no assumptions* about the interpreter of the output program. [Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KytbPis8LS0tLS0tXSxbWz4uPis8PC1dPisrKy4tPls8Lj4tXTwtLTwsXQ&input=Q29kZSBHb2xmIQ)

For a shorter solution (which works only with some interpreters), see [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83862).

#### Test run

For input `Code Golf`, the following output is generated.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-------------------------------------------------------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------------------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-----------------------------------------------------------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.---------------------------------
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy4tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLSsrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLSsrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0rKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy4tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLSsrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy4tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0rKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysuLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrLi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLSsrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKy4tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0&input=)

#### How it works

We begin by putting the integer **43** (character code of `+`) in the second cell of the tape. The following code achieves this.

```
++         Increment the first cell twice, setting it to 2.
[          While the first cell in non-zero:
  >+         Increment the second cell.
  <------    Decrement the first cell six times.
]
```

This essentially performs the modular division **2 ÷ 6 (mod 256)**. Since **(2 + 256) ÷ 6 = 258 ÷ 6 = 43**, the result is **43**, as intended.

Now we're ready to generate output.

```
,      Read a character from STDIN and put it the first cell.
[        While the first cell is non-zero:
  [        While the first cell is non-zero:
    >.     Print the content of the second cell ('+').
    >+     Increment the third cell.
    <<-    Decrement the first cell.
  ]      If the first cell held n, the above prints n plus signs
         and puts n in the third cell.
  >+++   Add three to the second cell, setting it to 46 ('.').
  .      Print its content ('.').
  -      Decrement, setting it to 45 ('-').
  >      Advance to the third cell.
  [      While the third cell is non-zero:
    <.     Print the content of the second cell ('-').
    >-     Decrement the third cell.
  ]      If the first cell held n, the above prints n minus signs,
         thus negating the plus signs and zeroing the cell of the output program.
  <--    Subtract 2 from the second cell, setting it back to 43.
  <,     Go back to the first cell and read another character from STDIN.
]      Once EOF is reached, ',' will put 0 in the first cell, ending the loop.
```

Comment: Aw, man! You can't break the crossed-out-44-is-44 meme, come on! Anyway your attempt to defeat it failed miserably because it doesn't look struck out, it looks like there is some dirt on my screen (PHP, perhaps?) :P

Comment: Anything to avoid that comment...

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth - 11 bytes

```
sm+*\+Cd".>
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%2B%2a%5C%2BCd%22.%3E&input=%22helloworld%21%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

### 05AB1E, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
vyÇ`'+×„.>J
```

**Explained**

```
v             # for each char in input string
 yÇ`          # convert to its ascii value
    '+×       # push the char '+' that many times
       „.>J   # push string ".>" and join with the plus signs
              # implicitly print combined string
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dnnDh2AnK8OX4oCeLj5K&input=aGk)

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Adnan

Comment: `'+×` instead of `F'+}` saves a byte.

Comment: @Adnan: Thanks! I was looking for a "repeat" command.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 98 bytes

```
class a{String A(char[]b){String z="";for(char B:b){for(int c=B;c-->0;)z+="+";z+=".>";}return z;}}
```

`String`s are nothing more than immutable `char[]`s with a bunch of utility methods, so let's use the array!

Ungolfed:

```
class a {
    void A(char[] b) {
        for (char B : b) {
            for (int c = B; c-- > 0;)
                 System.out.print('+');
            System.out.print(".>");
        }
    }
}
```

Equivalent standalone program that is 138 bytes long:

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){for(char b:A[0].toCharArray()){for(int B=b;B-->0;)System.out.print('+');System.out.print(".>");}}}
```

**Bonus:**

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){for(char b:new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File(A[0])).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().toCharArray()){for(int B=b;B>0;B--)System.out.print('+');System.out.print(".>");}}}
```

This 207-byte app actually encodes a file as a BF program, just as said in the title.

Comment: Is it just me or does the way the ungolfed program is indented look awesome?

Comment: Realized right before I posted that my answer is basically a golfed down version of yours.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 29 bytes

```
,[[+>+[---------.]<]--[--.],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzpa2047WhcG9GJtYnV1o0EMndj//zMyAQ)

**Explanation**:

```
,[                  loop over all characters on input
  [+                output number of minuses based on input
    >+[---------.]< print characters including -
  ]
  --[--.]           print all even characters in reverse equal to .,
,]
```

This solution expects classic 8-bit wrapping interpreter and uses the fact that other characters than `+-,.<>[]` are ignored by brainfuck interpreter. It also expects that generated program will be run with no input and thus receives null bytes as input - reading of input is used to clear the cell.

Statement generating `-` actually generates following string: `øïæÝÔËÂ¹°§zqh_VMD;2) üóêáØÏÆ½´«¢~ulcZQH?6-$`  , where the only interpretable character is `-`.

Statement generating `.,` actually generates `` üúøöôòðîìêèæäâàÞÜÚØÖÔÒÐÎÌÊÈÆÄÂÀ¾¼º¸¶´²°®¬ª¨¦¤¢ ~|zxvtrpnljhfdb`^\ZXVTRPNLJHFDB@><:86420.,*(&$" ``   where following characters are interpreted `><.,`. The `><` moves pointer right and then left, so it actually doesn't do anything.

Comment: [Running output](https://tio.run/##7dthKx1gHIbxpdGmJUmzWEtLMm1LJ2khW9KSbI2WpIUhsUkISZLOdMhkEkImJGRCSOjw4r4/2PF8C62uD/D8rvvF8/bfNvC9u7dzqP1nIuFLH3vXf73o347qSifa04aWNKtfo/1dLQ2fqsoir3Kz0pId95kPvOUV/3FMNzrXP21rVfOaGh/qaW@qq35f8iYvJ@PxA1BQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUND/H437OsAXPvepT3zkw/BwP2R2vO1Nb3jda4FZDtEFz3vOs57xtGOedNQTulVc17rURUichkFHOtSB9rWrnRDcDPPWtaYVLWtRCyE/F8bOaFoxTSqqifGx0ZHhwYG@3p4fXZ0dba3N35oaG77Wf/lcW1P9saryQ0V56buS4kjR29eFBfl5L3NfPM9@9jQzIz3tSeqjlIdJ/AhQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFAOXO73wCWRuAM) link

Answer (score 2):

## Sesos, 12 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 28cbf6 02e83d 655bae 243901                       (....=e[.$9.

Size   : 12 byte(s)
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=YWRkIDQzLGZ3ZCAxLGdldApqbXAKICBqbXAsc3ViIDEscndkIDEscHV0LGZ3ZCAxLGpuegogIGFkZCA0NixwdXQsYWRkIDE2LHB1dAogIGdldA&input=aGk&debug=on)

### Assembler

```lisp
add 43,fwd 1,get
jmp
  jmp,sub 1,rwd 1,put,fwd 1,jnz
  add 46,put,add 16,put
  get
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
I\[&'>.+'i1-\Du]Z

I                     Get the length of the input stack.
 \[            ]      Pop n, repeat this block of code n times.
   &                  Push a new stack and move to it.
    '>.+'             Push the string '+.>' to the stack.
         i            Pop an item from the input stack and push it to the current
                      program stack.
          1-          Subtract one from the top program stack item.
            \D        Duplicate the '+' in the stack that many times.
              u       Merge the current program stack with the previous.
                Z     Output the entire current stack as a string.
```

Note that this answer is one of the few times that I've ever used `I` and `u`. :D

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=SVxbJmlcWycrJ10nLj4ncnVdWg&input=&args=VGhlIGZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2cu)

Answer (score 2):

## K6, 16 bytes

```
,/{|">.",x#"+"}'
```

### Usage

```
,/{|">.",x#"+"}'"some string"
```

### Explanation

```
  {           }'  For each character in the string...
         x#"+"    Repeat "+" as many times as the character's ASCII code.
        ,         Combine that with...
    ">."          The code to print it and move on.
   |              But we put the string together backwards...so now it gets reversed.
,/                Combine all the substrings into one BIG string.
```

Comment: Explanation plz :D

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE Done! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [O](http://jadonfowler.xyz/o/), 13 bytes

```
i{'+n#*".>"}d
```

Explanation:

```
i              Read standard input into a string and push it onto the stack.
 {         }d  For each character in the string...
  '+           Push "+".
    n#         Convert the character (n) to its ASCII code.
      *        Multiply the "+" by the character code to get the number of +'s needed.
       ".>"    Push the string ".>".
               In O, the stack is printed after execution, so this prints out the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 43 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join('+'*ord(c)+'.>'for c in s)
```

The Python puts a number of pluses equivalent to the ASCII code of each character, followed by `.>` to print and move to the next cell.
The brainfuck increments up to the correct value, prints, and moves on to the next cell.

Output for `hi` (with newlines for clarity):

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>
```

That program's output:

```
hi
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 25 bytes

```
s/./"+"x ord($&).".>"/eg
```

### Usage

```
echo -n hi | perl -pe 's/./"+"x ord($&).".>"/eg'
```

### Explanation

Uses a regular expression replace operation to replace every character in every line given on standard input with a number of `+` calculated from the ordinal value of that character, then outputs `.>` to print and advance to the next character.

Uses the perl `-p` flag to automatically read the input and print the result, adding 1 extra to the bytecount.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 91 bytes

```java
String b(char[] f){String k="";for(char b:f){for(int u=b;u>0;u--)k+="+";k+=".>";}return k;}
```

Props to [dorukayhan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83857/45348) for beating me to it :)

Comment: You can't just remove the boilerplate and change all the names of the variables and then claim that as a new answer.

Comment: @LeakyNun I didn't, but I could if I wanted to.

Comment: How is this answer different from the answer you linked to?

Comment: @LeakyNun Downvote and move on

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, <s>67</s> <s>66</s> 61 Bytes

Simply iterate over each characters in the argument, and print a line for each one with `n` `+`s followed by `.>` where `n` is the value of this character in the ASCII Table.

**Uses gmatch as @LeakyNun advised in the comment for saving 1 Bytes over the the gsub solution**

```lua
for c in(...):gmatch"."do print(("+"):rep(c:byte())..".>")end
```

**Old solution using gsub**

```lua
(...):gsub(".",function(c)print(c.rep("+",c:byte())..".>")end)
```

**Old 67**

```lua
(...):gsub(".",function(c)print(string.rep("+",c:byte())..".>")end)
```

To run it, just save it as a file (`golf.lua` for instance) and run it with `lua golf.lua "hi"`. For `hi`, it should output

```lua
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>
```

Comment: How do I use this? Just pasting it in the REPL gives `attempt to index a nil value`, and `f = ...` gives the same, and `function f ... end` gives `unexpected symbol near ':'`

Comment: @cat Just save it in a file and run it as `lua file.lua "argument"`, I will update the post to give instructions.

Comment: How does that even work? is `...` an identifier with argv?

Comment: @cat `...` contains the values in the table `arg` unpacked. Which means it will always correspond to `arg[1]` unless you use it in a function call as the last parameter, then it will expend.

Comment: `n=...for n:gmatch"."do print(("+"):rep(c:byte())..".>")end` for 48 bytes

Comment: always forget the existence of `gmatch` ^^. also, shorter with `for(...):gmatch"."do print(("+"):rep(c:byte())..".>")end`, will update :)

Comment: @LeakyNun doesn't work as is, because the for loop isn't well declared, I'll see if I can do something.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>72</s> <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```c
main(c){for(;c=~getchar();)for(;printf(~c++?"+":".>")^2;);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```c
main( c )
{
    for ( ; c = ~getchar( ); )
        for ( ; printf( ~c++ ? "+" : ".>" ) ^ 2; );
}
```

Compile and test with:
`gcc -o bfcat bfcatgolf.c && cat 1.txt | ./bfcat > o.txt && beef o.txt`

#### Results

- `hi` - http://paste.ubuntu.com/17995958/
- `quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` - http://paste.ubuntu.com/17996059/
- source code - http://paste.ubuntu.com/18000808/

Comment: Why is `c` the bitwise inverse of `getchar`, especially if you just invert the inversion again?

Comment: @cat `c = ~getchar( )` evaluates to 0 on `EOF`. `c = ~getchar( )` and `~c++` are simply shorter than `~( c = getchar( ) )` and `c--`

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 12 bytes

Converts each character to its ASCII value, and increments the current cell by that number of times before printing it. Since we have infinite tape we can just move to the right after processing each character.

```
q{i'+*'.'>}%
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cXtpJysqJy4nPn0l&input=aGk)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 27 bytes

```
,[[>+[++++.+++]<-]--[.--],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzraTjtaGwj0gDjWRjdWVzdaT1c3Vif2///EJAA) [Try result](https://tio.run/##7drfKx5QHMfxtmZpiWXSEmtbkjZtS0vIlpa2xdKSaZOWeZaNrSeEtIQwmRAmEzITMvmVCT2z5@Lz@cMe50/YpYv33alz@r7ep87laep41xJt7op8SiSSUq5l3cq/X/SooqrmTeOHaFevhjSmac3rpza0o0P99aC/eco/vOx1b/uPYxeS0zJzcu8WlpQ/q37VEGlt7@nXiCY0q0Wt6rf2day4v3rc373gX970no/8DwwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDOy8YY771DGfhPWhD7zv3TBuK@xueM2rXgnAUjg/7znPeiaQk2HCmEc94uEQMaC4ThXTiY5C1kFQdrWtLW2G0LXgrmhZS1oI6XOhZEZTmtR4uMxoaBvWoAb6er/0dHd2tEU/t35sft/U@Lah/nVdbc3L6heVz59WPCl/XFZaXPSw8MG9gjv5ebm3b97IzrqemZF@NTXlSvLlSxd5BWBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGB8PP2vj6eJxBk)

Optimized from [Jiří's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247269)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 49 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...x].map(c=>'+'.repeat(c.charCodeAt())+.1)+0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADA47iLtNRfEAoRdInoY9ukB5ZiEt3eZk5@@ZF0xFy9bRlN@YydiOib6eIIYqzSipKLjjMIyc5pCKvrMyBqalDXpZNwP8E78mGDERQvohDLDw)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <del>40</del> 38 bytes

```
gets.chop.each_byte{|o|puts"+"*o+".>"}
```

Comment: I don't know ruby but I do know you can use `puts` instead of `print`, as the format of the output is not significant as long as it is valid brainfuck and brainfuck does not care about other characters

Comment: @cat oh I didn't know that bf ignores other characters, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## J, 28 bytes

```
[:;[:('.>',~'+'#~])"0[:]3&u:
```

Simple enough. `3&u:` converts chars to char codes. The rest is just repeat `'+'` that number of times, then concatenating with `.>` at the end of each line, and `;` flattens the result.

### Some results

```
   bf =: [:;[:('>.',~'+'#~])"0[:]3&u:
   bf 'hi'
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>. +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>.
   bf ' !'
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>. +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>.
   bf ' ~'
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>.
                 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 11 bytes

```
F.o\+*".>"+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=F.o%5C%2B%2a%22.%3E%22%2B&input=hi)

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 13 bytes

```
O`'+*".>"@`MΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=T2AnKyoiLj4iQGBNzqM&input=ImFiYyI)

The strategy used here is the same as in many of the other solutions - for each character, output enough `+`s to increment a zero-initialized cell to the proper ASCII ordinal, output it with `.`, and move to the next cell with `>`.

Explanation:

```
O`'+*".>"@`MΣ
O              list of ordinals (technically this is Unicode code points, but code points 0-127 are the same for Unicode and ASCII)
 `'+*".>"@`M   for each ordinal:
  '+*            push a string containing that many +s
     ".>"@       push ".>" and swap (putting it before the +s)
            Σ  concatenate all the strings (if "[", "]", and "," weren't meaningful characters in BF, this technically wouldn't be necessary)
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6, <s>119</s> 115 bytes

`f=s=>{a='';for(i in[...s]){b=s[c='charCodeAt'](i)-(s[c](i-1)|0);a+=(b>0?'+'.repeat(b):'-'.repeat(-b))+'.'}return a}`

Saved 4 bytes, thanks to @Leibrug

Comment: You can assign `charCodeAt` to some var (let's say `c`) and use like that: `s[c](i)` to shorten by 1 byte, and also remove some characters (i found 3: space before `[...s]`, replace logical OR with bitwise one, and semicolon before `return`).

Answer (score 1):

## Mouse-2002, 27 bytes

```
(?'l:l.^(l.^"+"l.1-l:)".>")
```

This works in theory and according to the language's documentation, but the reference implementation of Mouse's interpreter seems to have a bug where string input appends a `'`, so for `a` this outputs

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>
```

Which in turn outputs `a'`. That may or may not be okay, so here's a **39 byte**  long one which doesn't output `'` ever and thus is likely *more* invalid.

```
(?'l:l.39=l.0=+0=^(l.0>^"+"l.1-l:)".>")
```

Which gives right output in the reference impl. as long as there are no `'`s :)

Explained:

```
(              ~ while (true) {
  ?' l:        ~   l = getchar() 
  l. ^         ~   if (! (l) ) { break }
  (            ~   while (true) {
    l. ^       ~     if (! (l) ) { break }
    "+"        ~     puts("+")
    l. 1 - l:  ~     l-- // l = l - 1
  )            ~   }
  ".>"         ~   puts(".>")
)              ~ }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 58 bytes

```
[ [ [ 43 ] ""replicate-as ".>"append ] { } map-as ""join ]
```

Works like:

```
[ 
  [ 
    [ 43 ] "" replicate-as  ! ``+'' * code point, clone-like a string ""
    ".>" append             ! append ".>"
  ] 
  { } map-as                ! for each char in string and clone-like an array { }
  "" join                   ! join array of str into str by ""
]
```

Since Factor comes with a Brainfuck interpreter, it's simple to test.

**bfcat.factor**

```
USING: sequences ;
IN: bfcat

: string>brainfuck ( s -- bf )
  [ [ 43 ] "" replicate-as ".>" append ]
  { } map-as "" join ;
```

**bfcat-tests.factor**

```
USING: tools.test bfcat brainfuck ;
IN: bfcat.tests

{ "a"  } [ "a"  string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ] unit-test
{ "ab" } [ "ab" string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ] unit-test
{ "+++++++++++++" } [ "+++++++++++++" string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ] unit-test
{ "Code Golf" } [ "Code Golf" string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ] unit-test
```

**output**

```
Unit Test: { { "a" } [ "a" string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ] }
Unit Test: { { "ab" } [ "ab" string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ] }
Unit Test: {
    { "+++++++++++++" }
    [ "+++++++++++++" string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ]
}
Unit Test: {
    { "Code Golf" }
    [ "Code Golf" string>brainfuck get-brainfuck ]
}
```

Yay! they all pass.

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Bash, <s>100</s> 85 bytes

```
while IFS= read -rn1 c;do printf '+%.0s' $(seq 1 $(printf %d \'$c));echo '.>';done<$1
```

Thanks [@cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46231/cat) for saving me 15 bytes!

#### Postramble

1. Assumes input string is represented as-is in a file passed as first argument.
2. Usage: `bash bfcat.sh <path to file containing string>`
3. Usage (with named pipe): `bash bfcat.sh <(echo -n '<string>')`

#### Ungolfed

```
while IFS= read -r -n1 c # Read file byte by byte [1]
do
    n=$(printf "%d" \'"$c") # `ord` of a char in bash [2]
    printf '+%.0s' $(seq 1 $n) # emit character $n times [3]
    echo '.>' # Emit output and shift command for bf. I love infinite memory.
done <"$1"
```

#### References in Ungolfed version

1. [Read file byte by byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889659)
2. [`ord` of a char in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890262/)
3. [emit character $n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718)

Comment: I've improved some of the formatting and stuff in your answer, and removed redundant information from the links. Feel free to undo it if you don't like it. Also, it's GNU Bash, not GNU/Bash like GNU/Linux. :)

Comment: Golfing tips (I'm no bash golfer): `read -rn1`, get rid of spaces after `;`, get rid of the space in `done <"$1"` to save a total of 9 bytes

Comment: @cat It looks awesome! I really need to get in the habit of edit->preview->edit->...

Answer (score 1):

## [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef), 38 bytes

Hey, the same length as Ruby! just that Sidef isn't Ruby :D

```
read().bytes.each{|c|say"+"*c;say".>"}
```

Read some chars, then for each byte do that thing.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 50 Bytes

```
f[]=[]
f(x:y)=replicate(fromEnum x)'+'++".>"++f y
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, <del>39</del> 41 bytes

```
0i:@:0(?;\~~o!
v?:+"Ā"-$/'.'~
/.13-1o'+'
```

### Explanation

Add 256 to each char code, then print that many `+`, then `.`

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 26 bytes

```
gsub(/./){?+*$&.ord+'.>'}
```

+ 1 byte for the `p` command line option. To e.g get the brainfuck code for `ABC xyz` you can run

```
$ ruby -p -e 'gsub(/./){?+*$&.ord+".>"}' <<< "ABC xyz"
```

and get

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
Ç'+×„.>«J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLu69uHpjxrm6dkdWu31/79Hak5Ovo5CeH5RTooiAA)

```
Ç'+×„.>«J  # full program
        J  # join...
   ×       # runs of...
Ç          # codepoints of...
           # (implicit) each character in...
           # implicit input...
 '+        # literals...
       «   # with...
    „.>    # literal...
       «   # appended to...
           # (implicit) each element
           # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), <strike>69</strike>, 67 bytes

```
import strutils;for i in readLine stdin:echo repeat("+",i.int)&".>"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3nTNzC_KLShSKS4pKSzJziq3T8osUMhUy8xSKUhNTfDLzUoFSKZl5VqnJGflAsYLUxBINJW0lnUy9zLwSTTUlPTsliFFQExes9UjNycnXUQjPL8pJUYQIAgA)

*Wow, I beat ES6, that is a shock. Nim usually does a lot worse!*

Answer (score 0):

## [BinaryFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Binaryfuck), 12 bytes

`0x071cbb2593eeca31d084c0ef`

Technically, 11.5 bytes . But who counts fractions of bytes, anyways?

Yeah, I just took the shortest solution in Brainfuck and substituted it. (Hey, I shortened it by 19 bytes!) Here's a [hex to binary converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-binary.html) to convert the hexadecimal to binary.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 25 bytes

```
|R2I=@P[$n[b"+"]`b".>">]`
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7CR2I%3D%40P%5B%24n%5Bb%22%2B%22%5D%60b%22.%3E%22%3E%5D%60&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!)

## Explanation

```
|                  parse input
 R2                reformat as string
   I               split into chars and save into consecutive memory slots, move pointer to end
    =@             set top of stack to pointer value
      P            set pointer to 0
       [...]`      loop n times where n is the top of the stack (the old pointer)

$                  swap top of stack with value in storage at the pointer
 n                 get ASCII value of top of stack
  [....]`          loop n times where n is the top of the stack
   b"+"            add "+" to the print buffer
         b".>"     add ".>" to the print buffer
              >    move pointer to next slot
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `JB`, 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'+×`.>+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSclMkIlQzMlOTclNjAuJTNFJTJCJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9aGkmZmxhZ3M9SkJl)
or [verify the resulting BF program](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fm05Az06bflb9/w8A)

##### Explanation

```python
'+×`.>+  '# Implicit input
          # Cast to ordinals
'+×      '# Multiply by "+"
   `.>+   # Add ".>" to each
          # Join into a string
          # Implicit output
```